# How to convert c++ source code to js using Emscripten API?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, emscripten

Is there any [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) API on how to convert c++ source code file to js?

Comment: There is a [tutorial](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial).

Comment: I doubt that. But you can just `system()` the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are searching for this set of header files that can be included from your C/C++ code:

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/include/emscripten

For example, the html5.h file has functions to register callbacks for web browser user input.

Comment: useful link but the question is not about it. is there any API to run it with no process fork (emscripten executable run)